# mariadb server: I can't stop the server with `mysql.server stop`

Tags: mariadb

OSX 10.13.6

I installed mariadb sever with homebrew a few years ago, and I use it infrequently.  Today, I tried to start mariadb using the command:

```
$ mysql.server start
```

and I got a bunch of errors.  So, I did:

```
$ brew update
```

then:

```
$ brew uprade mariadb
```

That completed fine, and now I can start mariadb with:

```
$ mysql.server start
```

and I can access all my old db's.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot stop mysql.  Both these commands hang:

```
$ mysql.server stop
```

and(in another terminal window):

```
$ mysql.server status
```

According to the MariaDB docs for [mysql.server](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlserver/), both those commands should work.

Currently, I'm killing the server like this:

```
$ killall mysqld mysqld_safe
```

then checking that the server was killed with this:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysqld
```

When I run the ps command when mysql is running, I get:

> ~$  ps aux | grep mysqld
>   7stud   3707   0.0  1.0  4808208 79948 s005  S     1:26PM   0:00.47
>   /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.3.15/bin/mysqld
>   --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.3.15 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.3.15/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MacBook-Pro-2.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MacBook-Pro-2.local.pid
>
> 7stud   3643   0.0  0.0  4287792   1460 s005  S     1:26PM   0:00.02 /bin/sh
>   /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.3.15/bin/mysqld_safe
>   --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MacBook-Pro-2.local.pid
>
> 7stud   4544   0.0  0.0  4267752    880    s000  S+    1:41PM   0:00.00
>   grep mysqld

What is the proper way to shut down the mariadb server?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%vers%';
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                                    |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| innodb_version                  | 10.3.15                                  |
| protocol_version                | 10                                       |
| slave_type_conversions          |                                          |
| system_versioning_alter_history | ERROR                                    |
| system_versioning_asof          | DEFAULT                                  |
| thread_pool_oversubscribe       | 3                                        |
| version                         | 10.3.15-MariaDB                          |
| version_comment                 | Homebrew                                 |
| version_compile_machine         | x86_64                                   |
| version_compile_os              | osx10.13                                 |
| version_malloc_library          | system                                   |
| version_source_revision         | 07aef9f7eb936de2b277f8ae209a1fd72510c011 |
| version_ssl_library             | OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019              |
| wsrep_patch_version             | wsrep_25.24                              |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, tried to use **mysql.server stop** and **mysql.server status** after running **mysql.server start** but they will just run indefinitely.

If you are using a Mac seems that mysql.server stop won't work... I installed mariadb with homebrew and found out that I can use brew services to start and stop it in this link:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214883/homebrew-mariadb-server-start-error-with-mysql-server-start

The commands are pretty simple and they work for me

```
brew services start mariadb
brew services stop mariadb
```

It may be a little late but I hope this helps you to figure out your problem.

Comment: Note: using `brew services` persists after reboots therefore this approach isn’t equivalent as running `mysql.server start` or `mysql.server stop`.

Answer (score 5):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59938033/4579271 for details.

To fix, run:

```sh
cp /usr/local/bin/mysql.server /usr/local/bin/mysql.server.backup
sed -i "" "s/user='mysql'/user=\`whoami\`/g" /usr/local/bin/mysql.server
```

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, providing the functionality OP was looking for (non-persistent starts/stops).