# How can I fix brew-installed MariaDB that hangs on `mysql.server stop` and doesn’t stop?

Tags: macos, mariadb, homebrew

This question is not a duplicate of [mariadb server: I can't stop the server with `mysql.server stop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517828/mariadb-server-i-cant-stop-the-server-with-mysql-server-stop).

I don’t want to run MariaDB at boot so `brew services` isn’t an option.

MariaDB version is `10.4.11-MariaDB`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think I found the culprit.

Having a look at the source code of `mysql.server` (`cat /usr/local/bin/mysql.server`), I discovered that running `mysql.server start` runs `mysqld_safe` as me (`whoami`) which is what I expected.

Now, I also discovered that running `mysql.server stop` runs a `su_kill` function that runs `su` as `mysql` which fails because the `mysql` user doesn’t exist on macOS.

```sh
user='mysql'

su_kill() {
  if test "$USER" = "$user"; then
    kill $* >/dev/null 2>&1
  else
    su - $user -s /bin/sh -c "kill $*" >/dev/null 2>&1
  fi
}
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong, but according to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/), running `mysql.server start` is the right way of starting MariaDB on brew installs.

Anyhow, to patch `mysql.server stop`, run:

```sh
cp /usr/local/bin/mysql.server /usr/local/bin/mysql.server.backup
sed -i "" "s/user='mysql'/user=\`whoami\`/g" /usr/local/bin/mysql.server
```

Comment: `sed: /usr/local/bin/mysql.server: in-place editing only works for regular files` doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

Originally, whenever I tried `mysql.server stop` I would get the error:

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

At some point, `mysql.server stop` would just hang.

Exploring @sunknudsen's answer, I `cd`'ed to the directory:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
```

then I opened the file:

```
mysql.server
```

The code `user='mysql'` only appears on one line, so I just commented out that line and replaced it with:

```
185 #user='mysql'
186 user=`whoami`
```

Now, this is what happens:

```
~$ mysql.server start
Starting MariaDB
.200804 15:43:28 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MacBook-Pro-2.local.err'.
200804 15:43:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
 SUCCESS! 

~$ mysql.server stop
Shutting down MariaDB
. SUCCESS! 

~$ mysql.server stop
ERROR! MariaDB server PID file could not be found!
```

The correct start/stop status is also indicated in `System Preferences/MySQL`.

Comment: This works, however I would suggest as @sunknudsen to backup your mysql.server file before fiddling with it: `cp /usr/local/bin/mysql.server /usr/local/bin/mysql.server.backup
`.

Comment: @lata, When you comment out one line and replace it with one line, you have in effect backed up your `mysql.server` file: to revert to the original, you delete the line under the commented line and you uncomment the commented line.